# Would it be possible to change the way @community lifts things on frontpage

Tags: discussion, feature-request

When a post goes unhanded, it gets randomly lifted to the front page by the @community bot.

Many of the actions that get taken against certain kinds of posts is due to very big dislike of this behavior. On the other hand the community bot is doing a favor because its pointing out that maybe you missed this.

The central aspect is that it fills the front page on not so busy days with posts that could be more or less called community failures. Zombie posts that are destined to walk the exchange without a master, or anybody who would vote for a answer.

The argument is that I can filter questions, yes I can. But a first time visitor can not. Also there's a second argument often cited: They will eventually get handled. But really is 2-3 years later really good enough because that's what it means for certain posts.

So in order to facilitate more leniency on new askers, thus allowing a larger question base. Could or should:

- The algorithm be changed somehow
- @community be throttled back a bit

This would probably go a long way into solving certain issues. What do you think?

Comment: Don't think its possible but sure wish it was. Stupid bump-bot.

Comment: @Ryan have you tried banning him :)

Comment: Is it possible for @community raised posts to only be visible to members with more than 150 rep, for example?
Would it be good if newer members saw the better, new questions more, so they could learn from the example set by those, and not old weird questions?

Comment: Well, newer questions aren't necessarily better. :)

Comment: Couldn't it also be an option to give mods the power of Accepting answers?

Comment: @PieBie  no..  we do not know if that has in fact answered their question.  The better alternative is to encourage the OP with a comment to accept an answer or make an edit

Comment: Of course, that should always be the first step. But if the OP hasn't shown any activity for, say, a year, it's quite possible they're never coming back. In that case I think a mod should be able to select the best answer. Either that, or mark the question as 'abandoned' or something.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of downvoting the question I usually request in a comment that the OP accept an answer or make an edit.  Time usually isn't an issue.  In fact just the other day I pinged the OP and the question had been idle for over a year and they came back and accepted.

If the question doesn't meet the criteria we've talked about there is no reason to modify Community.  Every member can make an edit and if their rep count is low it can go through the Q.

As JohnB stated in a comment.  If the community doesn't want to see old questions cycle through the homepage then upvote when its a valid answer.  Referenced: "[What can cause a question to be bumped?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48578/what-can-cause-a-question-to-be-bumped)"

Answer (score 0):

What I do..

If an old question **has answers** but the original poster **never selected** an answer..... I down vote the question.

If it's a **bad question** from the beta days I vote to close the question.

I don't believe community bumps negatively voted questions. It bumps no vote or positive voted questions. (I could be wrong on that though -- I've just never seen a -1 question bumped by Community.)

Comment: You're right about the bumping—[The Community user will bump non-negatively scored questions that have at least one answer scoring 0 and none scoring more than that](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/48579/216955). So the other alternative is to upvote one of the answers (if you can confirm that it's a correct answer worthy of an upvote, of course).

Comment: I do up vote answers as well, if I think I should. I just didn't realize that in itself has an effect on Community. And my single down vote on a question doesn't necessarily mean that the question is then at a negative score. So if more did this, it may have a greater impact.